# Parsing lines between two matching strings, excluding the second string from parsing

Tags: python

I want to parse lines between two strings that occur repetitively in a file. The first string marks the beginning of the target lines and the last string marks the end. I would not want the end string to be included.

This question https://askubuntu.com/questions/786922/how-to-capture-lines-between-two-strings-from-a-file-but-only-the-last-occurren is close to what capture only the last occurrence of the chunk of target lines.

Borrowing on that example, and assuming that my file looks as so:

```
ERROR - Second tech sync failed with rsync error code 255 at Fri May 27 13:50:4$
--------------------------------------------------------------------
After_sync script completed successfully with no errors.
Main script finished at Fri May 27 13:50:43 BST 2016 with PID of 18808.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2016
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
37 approvals pending.
Transfer completed successfully at Fri May 27 14:05:16 BST 2016
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Local repository verification started at Fri May 27 14:35:02 BST 2016
...

ERROR - Second tech sync failed with rsync error code 255 at Fri May 27 13:50:4$
--------------------------------------------------------------------
After_sync script completed successfully with no errors.
Main script finished at Fri May 27 13:50:43 BST 2016 with PID of 18808.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2017
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
ERROR: transfer not complete by end of log file
Transfer completed successfully at Fri May 27 14:05:16 BST 2017
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Local repository verification started at Fri May 27 14:35:02 BST 2016
...
ERROR - Second tech sync failed with rsync error code 255 at Fri May 27 13:50:4$
--------------------------------------------------------------------
After_sync script completed successfully with no errors.
Main script finished at Fri May 27 13:50:43 BST 2016 with PID of 18808.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2018
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
ERROR: transfer not complete by end of log file
Transfer completed successfully at Fri May 27 14:05:16 BST 2018
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Local repository verification started at Fri May 27 14:35:02 BST 2018
...
```

How should I modify this code:

```
start = "Transfer started at"
end = "Transfer completed successfully"
buffer = ""
log = False

for line in open('test.txt'):
       if line.startswith(start):
              buffer = line
              log = True
       elif line.startswith(end):
              buffer += line
              log = False
       elif log:
              buffer += line

#print(buffer)
```

Such that instead of printing the last chunk, it should print all chunks in between start and end strings, excluding the end string?

The expected output mighty be structured as so:

```
2016: Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2016
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
37 approvals pending.

2017: Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2017
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
ERROR: transfer not complete by end of log file

2018: Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2018
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
ERROR: transfer not complete by end of log file
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a chunk of the input file that corresponds output string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is probably your best bet:

```
import re

start = "Transfer started at"
end = "Transfer completed successfully"

with open('test.txt', 'r') as test_file:
    test_file_text = test_file.read()
    desired_output = '\n'.join(re.findall(rf'(?s){start}.*?(?={end})', test_file_text))

print(desired_output)
```

Gets you this output:

```
Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2016
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
37 approvals pending.

Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2017
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
ERROR: transfer not complete by end of log file

Transfer started at Fri May 27 13:50:45 BST 2018
Logs transferred successfully.
Images transferred successfully.
Hashes transferred successfully.
ERROR: transfer not complete by end of log file
```

Alternatively, if you want to simply modify your current structure, this will get you the same output:

```
start = "Transfer started at"
end = "Transfer completed successfully"
buffer = ""
log = False

with open('test.txt', 'r') as test_file:
    for line in test_file:
        if line.startswith(start):
            log = True
        elif line.startswith(end):
            log = False
            buffer += "\n"

        if log:
            buffer += line

print(buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `+` operator in your code. Write it as:

```
if line.startswith(start):
    buffer += line
```

and I think you will get the result you want.

Comment: They would also need to replace the `buffer += line` in the `elif line.startswith(end):` if they wanted to avoid adding the last (undesired) line to the buffer. To get the proper spacing, this should be replaced with `buffer += '\n'` to separate each block.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for the hint. I was too focused to the why the code only show a block of output